# Оповещения spring angular

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

Здравствуйте, друзья, подскажите, делаю веб приложение на spring mvc + angular. Задача показывать оповещения (модальное окно или еще что-то) при наступлении конкретной даты и времени. Как такое организовать? Новичок в этом, ни разу не сталкивался.